# SQL create reverse column to huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table (billions of rows) in my database, which is in simple recovery model, and I need to create reverse index for one column.

What is the fastest way to do it?

The obvious way is too slow and using the log files very extensively:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
    ADD COLUMN Reverse_Column1 nvarchar(50);

UPDATE MyTable 
SET Reverse_Column1 = REVERSE(Column1);

CREATE INDEX idx_Reverse_Column1 ON MyTable (Reverse_Column1);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: no it is not obvious, as you said you need that index and so you must live with it

Comment: Do you already have an index on `Column1` ? If so - couldn't you just reverse the text being searched for, in your SQL queries, to use this existing index?

Comment: Creating index on a computed column would be quicker, but I would try above suggestion first.

Comment: @marc_s
i need the reverse index to quickly search for srting ending ('%searchValue')

Comment: Even if you had an index - searching for `%searchValue` will ***NEVER EVER*** be able to use that .....

Comment: Searching for `eulaVhcraes%` on an indexed reversed column though....

Comment: @marc_s  as Stu said, i can search the reverse ending of the string and this will use the reverse index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to search for `Column1` strings *ending* with a suffix then an index on `Column1` won't help you.

There is no need to add this column to the data page rows and incur all the logging for that though. You can add it as a *non persisted* computed column (metadata only).

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
    ADD Reverse_Column1 as REVERSE(Column1);
```

When you create an index on it then the values are persisted in the index only.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Reverse_Column1 ON MyTable (Reverse_Column1);
```

this will entail some logging but that is unavoidable. You can create the index `ONLINE` if you are on an edition supporting that to reduce blocking on the table for the duration of the operation.

Comment: this is exactly my motivation but my problem is with the update of a huge table

Comment: @rotem - this answer doesn't suggest that you update a huge table. You'll need to create an index on it though but this is unavoidable that you can't create an index without creating an index.

Comment: by update i means the creating of the reverse column, which is long operation. i'm tring to update/create the reverse column by batches..

Comment: @rotem - the creation of the reverse column as a non persisted computed column as suggested in my answer is a metadata only change. So essentially you are doing something entirely different from what I suggest and then moaning to me about it

Comment: thanks a lot! at start i didnt notice you suggest doing computed column, now i created non persisted computed column and indexed it and it works great!